# Java: Transform CSV file TO BINARY file

Tags: java, database, csv, binary

This is one of the problems for my homework in my Database class.

I don't understand why we need to transform the csv file into binary file. i think that way will make it harder to search the data. Can anyone tell me why we need to do that? Is my teacher fooling me or it is really better to transform a csv file to binary file in order to read with binary search method. An example of one row of the csv file is

```
1|37|O|131251.81|1996-01-02|5-LOW|Clerk#000000951|0|nstructions sleep furiously among
```

This is the assignment that my teacher gave me. 
and i am really stuck at task C.

Overview
The objective of this assignment is to help you understand the issues involved in querying large data sets that are too large to fit in memory in its entirety. To investigate those issues, you will write a java program to read a table of data in the form of a CSV file and run queries on the table as efficiently as possible. A template of the program is provided and your code should be added to the Assignment1.java file. A driver program, Driver.java is provided so that you can test your program. The driver program takes as input a file which contains a list of commands to be interpreted and executed by the program. You will be implementing several versions of the program in a guided fashion. In all versions, you must assume that the data may not fit in memory, i.e., you will not be able to read all the data into an in-memory java data structure.

In all versions, the basic sequence of commands begins by loading the data, followed by a series of queries which are either equality queries or range queries. You may assume that the input is correct and well-behaved, i.e., the goal of this assignment is not error-handling.
Task A (15 pts)
In the first version, you will implement the simplest and most naive solution. The list of commands supported by your java program must include the following:

naiveLoad filename : tells the program that the following queries will be for the csv file with filename
naiveSearchEq columnNum value: prints the rows of the table where the value in column number columnNum is equal to the given value. Column numbers start from one.
naiveSearchGtr columnNum value: prints the rows of the table where the value in column number columnNum is greater than the given value.

The search commands should be implemented by reading the CSV file character by character using the java class FileReader. You should read the java documentation for FileReader, InputStreamReader etc. You MUST use the FileReader class. 
Task B (15 pts)
In the second version, you will improve upon the first version by using buffered IO. Write a second version of the search commands using theBufferedReader class. Name the commands and corresponding methods as follows:

naiveBufSearchEq columnNum value: prints the rows of the table where the value in column number columnNum is equal to the given value. Column numbers start from one.
naiveBufSearchGtr columnNum value: prints the rows of the table where the value in column number columnNum is greater than the given value.

Task C (50 pts)

In the third version, you will take a different approach to the problem. You will first load the CSV data file and transform it into a BINARY file. You MUST name your binary file "data.bin". Subsequent queries will then operate on the binary file. You are free to design the format of the binary file. Name the commands and corresponding methods as follows:

binaryLoad filename : transform the csv file with filename into a binary file. The filename of the binary file should be stored in your program. 
binarySearchEq columnNum value: prints the rows of the table where the value in column number columnNum is equal to the given value. Column numbers start from one.
binarySearchGtr columnNum value: prints the rows of the table where the value in column number columnNum is greater than the given value.

Task D (20 pts)
Take timings of version 1, 2, and 3 of your program and compare the running times. You should average the timings over at least 10 runs. In the inline submission on laulima, answer the following questions:

```
Tabulate the average running time of the three versions of your program. Compare the running times of the three versions.
How are the timings of the different versions different?
Why are the timings of the different versions different ?
What did you learn in this assignment? What was most difficult/challenging (if any)?
```

Comment: That's not enough information to understand why you are being asked to do this.  It is clearly in preparation for a future task, but without knowing what follows it is impossible to tell you why or suggest a possible design.  Also, you should use _some_ care in writing your question. I fixed the errors this time, but compilers are not as forgiving as humans.

Comment: It's quite common for teachers to come up with arbitrary constraints to make a task more interesting/difficult.

Comment: There's clearly some missing context (i.e. what is meant by "binary file").

Comment: As @JimGarrison already mentioned, the binary file may have advantages if it comes to more complex tasks later. Consider a select query just returning the rows in which a given column does have a certain value. Of course, just converting the ASCII file into a binary format will not yet provide any benefits. So the question is what kind of binary format you are required to implement? An intro from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_storage_structures

Comment: The purpose of this assignment to calculate how much time we needed to load csv file and search line by line to get the rows that match the required value.   So at task one, we used fileloader to load the csv file and process the naive search char by char method.  At task two, we added bufferloader in it, and process the naive search line by line, it seems faster. Then at task 3, i need to transform the csv file into binary file and do binary search method, then i am really lost here. I dun know how binary file work. Please give me a hint.

Comment: reply to @Jim Garrison          My teacher said the BINARY FILE can be free to design any format, but gotta name it to data.bin

Comment: I think you're confusing "binary file" with "binary search".  The two are completely unrelated.  The primary requirement for a "binary search" is that the data be sorted on the key you will be using to search it.

Comment: So you should optimize the file for a binary search algorithm. I'd do this: first, load the CSV rows into memory (an array per column and/or row). Then implement the binary search per on the in-memory structure. Second, this enables you to get an idea how the binary format should look like. I guess it will be some kind of column oriented as that will boost performance of the search operations (you do not have to scan each row, instead you can directly jump to a given column and perform the search on it).

Comment: @home    thank you, your algorithm is quite helpful. I think thats why the teacher want us to use binary search on a binary file, but how the teach said we have to assume we dun have enough ram fill all the data into, for example, a 30GB csv file cant load into our ram at once.

Comment: @user1933421: That's what I meant. Try to split the problem into smaller pieces. Work on the algorithm first (with some in-memory data). After you did this, implement the storage layer... nice exercise for building a small API as well :-)

Comment: Since it's a database course, I believe you've heard a data structure called B-Tree? If not you should look it up. It seems the way to go if you are having trouble loading the entire dataset into memory.

Comment: B-Tree is binary tree right? but i dun think its gonna be helpful at this assignment right? or u mean I should try to store the csv datas into a binary tree format?  this sounds interesting, but seems hard to do it,right? or is it even possible?

Comment: @aishwarya: please read the [homework] tag wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the updated objectives I would make a pass through the file and build a ***sorted index*** on the key. The index would contain key values and the offset of each record with that key.  I would then write a new file consisting of the index followed by the original data. If you are allowed to use two files, just write the index to disk as a separate file.

The index will be MUCH smaller than the original file.  When you need to search, read only the index portion (or file), look up the key using a binary search, retrieve the offset from the index entry, and use that offset to seek into the data and read only that record.

If even the index is too large to fit into RAM, then you have to build it in two steps.

1. Read the data file and write the index file, **un**sorted, one record at a time
2. Use a disk sort utility to sort the index

Comment: wow, index and offset is a great idea.  but how do i build that up? any tutorial out there? is it still good with binary search?

Comment: I think at this point you need to do your homework and research.  Remember that for a binary search the keys have to be in the correct order (i.e. sorted).

Comment: Is there a single key to sort on ???; From the question, you can search on any field number???